# Installing RVM error

Tags: command-line, 15.04, rvm, ruby-on-rails

I am trying to install RVM for [Ruby on Rails](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruby_on_Rails). This message appears:

> Requirements installation failed with status: 100.

What do I need to do? How do I fix this?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18947072/error-while-installing-ruby-using-rvm

Comment: How were you trying to install?